# Creating an infoWindow on Google Maps from KML file markers?

Tags: google-maps

All the Google docs show how to create an adjacent div to the right or left of the map and displaying the infoWindow there.

I want to create a popup infoWindow on based on base of the marker after being read in from a KML file.

This is what the Google docs show

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>KML Click Capture Sample</title>
    <style>
      html, body {
        height: 370px;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        }
      #map {
       height: 360px;
       width: 300px;
       overflow: hidden;
       float: left;
       border: thin solid #333;
       }
      #capture {
       height: 360px;
       width: 480px;
       overflow: hidden;
       float: left;
       background-color: #ECECFB;
       border: thin solid #333;
       border-left: none;
       }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <div id="capture"></div>
    <script>
      var map;
      var src = 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/kml/westcampus.kml';

      function initMap() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(-19.257753, 146.823688),
          zoom: 2,
          mapTypeId: 'terrain'
        });

        var kmlLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer(src, {
          suppressInfoWindows: true,
          preserveViewport: false,
          map: map
        });
        kmlLayer.addListener('click', function(event) {
          var content = event.featureData.infoWindowHtml;
          var testimonial = document.getElementById('capture');
          testimonial.innerHTML = content;
        });
      }
    </script>
    <script async
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I don't want to use the #capture div, rather i want to anchor the infoWindow on top of the rendered Marker on my Google Map. Something like...

```
  contentString='html here';

  const infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: contentString,
    ariaLabel: "Uluru",
  });

  const marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: uluru,
    map,
    title: "Uluru (Ayers Rock)",
  });

  marker.addListener("click", () => {
    infowindow.open({
      anchor: marker,
      map,
    });
  });
}
```

Both code snippets taken from the Google Docs on Maps ...https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/infowindows

Comment: Why do you use `suppressInfoWindows: true` then?

Comment: As MrUpsidown indicated, the default behavior is to create InfoWindows on the markers.  What issue are you having doing that?  Does the default HTML in the InfoWindow not work for you for some reason? [fiddle with the posted KML](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/ekjuv0hs/)  (from the ["simple" KML example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-kml) in the documentation, just changing the KML)

Answer (score 0):

This is what i came up with...

```
  var kmllayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
    map: map,
    url: src,
    suppressInfoWindows: true
  });

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

  google.maps.event.addListener(kmllayer, 'click', function(evt) {
    infowindow.setContent(evt.featureData.name + '<p>' + evt.featureData.description +  "<p>Include my location: <input type='checkbox' name='share_location' ></p>" + "<iframe src='http://127.0.0.1:5000/' width='100%' height='500' style='border: 0px;' id='chatgpt_iframe' ></iframe>") ;
    infowindow.setPosition(evt.latLng);
    infowindow.open(map);
  })
```